# Set the CurrentPrincipal failed when using UI event In Winform

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

All

I met an issue when I trying to set Thread.CurrentPrincipal on a WinForm Application.

There are two button on Form, Button1 and Button2. Button1 set the Thread.CurrentPrincipal and Button2 show the CurrentPrincipal. Everything works well so far.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SetPermission();
}

private void SetPermission()
{
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new MyPrinciple() { User = "xxxx" };
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Tread principal:{0},{1}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, Thread.CurrentPrincipal.ToString());
}
```

Then I changed some code. 
I want to auto set the principal once Form shown.So I added a event on Form.Shown.

```
void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { SetPermission(); }));
}

public Form1()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Shown += Form1_Shown;
}
```

When I click the button2 to show the princpal, I saw nothing.

I tried to set the principal on the Form's constructor. Then I got the result expected when I clicked button2.

```
public Form1()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        //this.Shown += Form1_Shown;
        SetPermission();
}
```

I searched on Google, By now, I have no idea about it. What's the different between those two ways?

Thanks you very much.

Comment: did you test calling SetPermissio() without Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(..)?

Comment: Yes, same result. Cannot get the Principle.

Comment: Hm.. is there an error? which? Or doesn't the handler or SetPermisiion() get executed? PLease notice that the Shown event is only dispatched once- the first time when a form is shown.

Comment: Yes, I debug it. It absolutly executed. Also no error. It failed when I trying to invoke button1.PerformClick in Constructor. Hm...Seems that all the event method cannot work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that has another reason. You have to wait for Form.Load before invoking the buttons event. Don't do that in your cntr.

Comment: Thank you, Wolfgang. In my mind, Form.Shown is executed after Form.Load, right? But it's still not work.

Comment: yes it is- this was realted to you last comment "I trying to invoke button1.PerformClick in Constructor"

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(new MyPrinciple() { User = "xxxx" })
```

instead of

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new MyPrinciple() { User = "xxxx" };
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Wolfgang. I tried it. Actually, I saw myPrinciple when clicking button2, but I have another question here: why I cannot see my principal after "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(new MyPrinciple() { User = "xxxx" })" in the setPermission method.

Comment: Sorry. I do not know myself for sure: I think it has something to do on how system and application threads get synchronized. I looked at one of my solutions how I did it because I had the same issue once a while.